# Get mp3 file from storage laravel

Tags: laravel

I've got mp3 files uploaded in the storage of laravel so they are protected and not findable for other people. Now I want the mp3 file to play in an audio tag of html. This seems to work but when I inspect the element and get the url of the audio tag and follow this in a new tab I get the audio file. This is not what I want cuz people may not see this file.

I already tried following code. But when you inspect the element of the audio tag and you follow the url you still get the file.

blade.php

```
<audio controls style="height:54px;"><source src="{{ route('getAudio', $song['name']) }}"></audio>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/get-audio/{filename}', 'SongsController@getAudio')->name('getAudio');
```

SongsController.php

```
public function getAudio($filename){ $fileContents = Storage::disk('local')->get('temporary_songs/'.$filename); $response = Response::make($fileContents, 200); $response->header('Content-Type', "audio/mpeg"); return $response; }
```

I just want that you can play the file in an audio tag but they can't get the file.

Comment: The question should be reworded => 'How to embed a mp3 file from Laravel storage to HTML audio tags'

Answer (score 1):

Route

```
Route::get ( '/audio/{file?}/{extension?}',  "YourController@embedAudio" );
```

Controller

```
public function embedAudio( Request $request ){

    $filePath = storage_path() . '/app/' . $request->file . '.' . $request->extension;


    try {
        $file = file_exists ( $filePath );
    }   
    catch (FileNotFoundException $e) {
        return \Redirect::back()->withErrors([ "File doesn't exist" ]); 
    }   
    return response()->file( $filePath );
}
```

View

```html
            <audio controls="" style="vertical-align: middle" src="/audio/file_name/mp3" type="audio/mp3" controlslist="nodownload">
                Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do create a Rewrite rule in your .htaccess and create dynic link from database and can update that link daily so when ever anyone go to the link from website will able to open link but this link will be availabe only for some period.
You can read and write files with the [file system functions](http://php.net/ref.filesystem), for example:

```
$data = <<<EOF
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule …
EOF;
file_put_contents('.htaccess', $data);
```

But it would be more flexible if you use one static rule that redirect the requests to your PHP file that then does the rest.

and

RewriteEngine On

```
 RewriteRule ^DynamicLink/(.*) /uploads/subfolder/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: This is not helping, cuz you can still find out the file only if it is for a short period time.

Comment: whatever you do can't run from 'Streaming Audio Recorder'